# Why is this working in the terminal but not in my shell script?

Tags: sql, linux, if-statement, sh, nagios

I am checking a database table for this source_date in order to make sure particular files were uploaded. This source_date changes whenever a task is done to upload these files and a script is ran on the linux server. I want to provide a warning when it is a Thursday and the source_date is an earlier date. When the person with the role does not complete the task after that date it should provide a CRITICAL message. The message is OK when the files are uploaded on the Thursday or on a later date.

I have ran this through the terminal and it comes out with the correct output but not the same when doing in in my shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh
STATE_OK=0
STATE_WARNING=1
STATE_CRITICAL=2
STATE_UNKNOWN=3
#
#
LEVEL_WARNING=1
LEVEL_CRITICAL=2
#
#
script_name=$(basename $0)
output_file='/tmp/fs'
TEMP_DIR='/tmp'
SQL_USER='<USERNAME>'
SQL_SCHEMA='<PASSWORD>'
DATE=$(date +"%d-%^b-%y")
TODAY=$(date +"%u")
LAST=$(date --date="last thursday" +"%d-%^b-%y") 
#LAST='14-JUN-18'
THIS=$(date --date="this thursday" +"%d-%^b-%y")
exit_code=$STATE_OK
exit_string=''
free_space=0

# Check that the sanctions are up-to-date
function check_fs {
    touch "$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql
        if [ $? != 0 ]
        then
            echo 'Unable to create sql command file'
        exit "$STATE_CRITICAL"
    fi
    echo 'SET HEADING OFF'                                                                  >"$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql
    echo 'SET SPACE 0'                                                                      >>"$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql
    echo 'SET NEWPAGE 0'                                                                    >>"$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql
    echo 'SELECT SOURCE_DATE'                                                               >>"$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql
    echo 'FROM <TABLE>'                                                         >>"$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql
    echo 'WHERE ROWNUM = 1;'                                                                >>"$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql
    echo 'exit;'                                                                            >>"$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql 

    sqlplus -S $SQL_USER/$SQL_SCHEMA  @"$TEMP_DIR"/"$script_name".sql >$output_file
    sql_result="$(cat $output_file)"
    #sql_result="27-JUN-18"
    #TODAY="3"
    set -x

    # If the source_date isn't equal to the last Thursday date or if the source_date is less than last Thursday date or if today is Thursday
    if [ "$sql_result" = "$DATE" ] && [ "$TODAY" = "4" ];
    then
        echo 'OK - The source_date is on the ('$sql_result'). Today is ('$DATE').'
        exit "$STATE_OK"
    elif [ "$sql_result" > "$LAST" ];
    then
        echo 'OK - The source_date is on the ('$sql_result'). Today is ('$DATE').'
        exit "$STATE_OK"
    elif [ "$TODAY" = "4" ] && [ "$sql_result" != "$DATE" ];
    then
        echo 'WARNING - The source date is ('$sql_result') on the table. Please perform the steps for the FSL.'
        echo 'Last Thursday was ('$LAST').'
        exit "$STATE_WARNING" > /tmp/out 2>/tmp/err
    else
        echo 'CRITICAL - The source date is ('$sql_result') on the table! Please update the FSL as soon as possible!! The FS should have been completed on the ('$LAST').'
        exit "$STATE_CRITICAL"
    fi 


}

# Start script:
. /home/nagios/setdb.sh > /dev/null

check_fs

echo ""
echo "$exit_string"
exit "$exit_code"
```

**Output:**

```
WARNING - The source date is (28-JUN-18) on the table. Please perform the steps for the FSL.
Last Thursday was (21-JUN-18).
```

**Intended Output:**

```
OK - The source_date is on the (28-JUN-18). Today is (28-JUN-18).
```

**Output in the Terminal:**
Added after made changes suggested by @hootnot

```
+ '[' 'ERROR:
ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied' = 28-JUN-18 ']'
+ '[' 'ERROR:
ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied' ']'
+ echo 'OK - The source_date is on the (ERROR:' ORA-12546: TNS:permission 'denied). Today is (28-JUN-18).'
OK - The source_date is on the (ERROR: ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied). Today is (28-JUN-18).
+ exit 0
```

Edited: To reflect what @JNevill mentioned with this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72039/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-equal-signs-in-shell-compari)

Comment: Is there a shebang in this script, does it match your shell? You have `sh` tagged, but then you use the non-standard `[[` which may not be supported and you mix `[` with `[[` in the same `If` suggesting that perhaps there is a misunderstanding of what shell you are in or the intricacies of the `[` and `[[` commands and where they are supported. [this may be enlightening](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72039/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-equal-signs-in-shell-compari)

Comment: run it in debugmode by using *set -x* and redirect output: *> /tmp/out 2>/tmp/err* and see what it did during execution

Comment: hey yeah, sorry it is #!/bin/sh

Comment: @hootnot I've made those changes.

Comment: "I have ran this through the terminal ...." , Equally important to using the correct `#!/bin/*sh`, in your script, is that your terminal has launched the same shell in your terminal. I really don't think you want to use `/bin/sh`. Why not just make everything `#!/bin/bash` and be happy? ;-) ? An original `#!/bin/sh` can't execute code like `var=$( cmd )`, you'd need to use backticks (too hard to illustrate in a comment, search `[sh]` Q for examples. Good luck.

Comment: seen the debugging output, I would say you must seek it in the ORACLE access. A *ORA-... permission denied* is very clear. You need to provide the script with the proper ORACLE environment variables

Comment: ... I also asume this is only a part of the script, since you only process some variables in the piece you posted. That piece alone can't give the oracle errors

Comment: @hootnot I have amended the above to include the other vital parts to the document.

Comment: running sqlplus this way you have a security issue: when you run the shell a *ps* exposes sqlplus with commandline options. I'm not an oracle guru, but I guess you need to set thing up differently to circumvent this. If I recall corectly there is something like *tnsnames.ora*. Now your issue: try to run simply your *sqlplus* from the commandline: *sqlplus -S user/passwd /tmp/thescript.sql. Replace user/passwd/thescript with the right values. If that is ok check your script and fix the variables. If you still have an issue dive into oracle sqlplus

Comment: @hootnot Nah, I think that "ERROR: ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied" comes up now and again.  I did what you said and I got the date back "28-JUN-18" with no errors.

Comment: you access the same oracle environment ? if you do *which sqlplus* is that the same as the one you call in the script ? If this sqlplus worked from the commandline and not from the script if definitely is an oracle environment issue. What does it do when you create a script with only this command in it? I guess now that *nagios/setdb.sh* is the source of your issue. Unless you run it as *nagios* yourself, you have different users here

Comment: and ... as the other suggestions say, use: #!/bin/bash